# my bootstrap 4 carousel wont display images

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The navigation is working but the carousel makes me feel like smashing my laptop.

The carousel wont display images only shows some three dots sliding using bootstrap 4.1.2

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>``

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width",initial-scale="1">
<title>master c&f</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!---Navigation--->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" >
 <div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/"></a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
<ul class="nabar-nav ml-auto">
 <li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item ">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">clearing</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item ">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">forwading</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item ">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">warehousing</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item ">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">enquires</a>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</nav> 

<!----Image slider---->
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img/back.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/FRONT.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="img/BOAT.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
 








 </body>
 </html>
```

What could be wrong with this code or why wont it work?

Comment: Can you please post a working example? Your current code is not working.

Comment: could you tell us more about your file-structure? your html-file at the same location as your img-directory?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that i can see here that will cause image loading problems is the directory's. I mean the location of the images. if the path 'img' is located inside other path like public/img/name.jpg you must type the full route. Other reason is if you use php frme work you must use something like base_url() or site_url() before the path. Most of the time the options that specify the paths are in a config file, which hase the full route to the project containing folder.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main problem here is due to your images path.
Using some image found in google, and simply changing the src of the carousel's images in your snippet, it's working good.

The 3 dots you see in your code, are due to the `alt="..."` attribute. If you write something here (as you should), you will see that text if the image is not found.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>``

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width",initial-scale="1">
<title>master c&f</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!---Navigation--->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top" >
 <div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/"></a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
 <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
<ul class="nabar-nav ml-auto">
 <li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item ">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">clearing</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item ">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">forwading</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item ">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">warehousing</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nav-item ">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">enquires</a>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</nav> 

<!----Image slider---->
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://staticr1.blastingcdn.com/media/photogallery/2018/6/24/660x290/b_1200x675/ciao-compie-200-anni-il-celebre-saluto-inizio-a-diventare-comune-dal-1818-vitaesteticait_2039115.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="2018/02/13/172803766-5059c7e1-5f17-49f3-b9ee-128dee78981a.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Image not found...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://st3.depositphotos.com/5269571/12517/v/950/depositphotos_125175688-stock-illustration-ciao-italian-greeting.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
 








 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your carousel is fine. Just make sure the paths to the images are correct. What is your directory structure?

Below I have used public images:

```css
.carousel {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!----Image slider---->
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/600/?random">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/600/?gravity=north">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://picsum.photos/1200/600/?gravity=west">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```